# In an ASP.Net vNext site, why does a migrations-related exception appear at startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have no migrations defined but I am still seeing an exception about the `__MigrationHistory` table at startup, after a lengthy timeout.

My initialization code looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<DiContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("ConnectionString")));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  var loggerFactory = (ILoggerFactory)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory));
  loggerFactory.AddProvider(
      new DiagnosticsLoggerProvider(
        new SourceSwitch("SourceSwitch", "Information"),
        new ConsoleTraceListener()));

  Trace.WriteLine("Configure.");

  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseErrorPage();
  app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

The exception:

```
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryExecutor Error: 0 : An exception occurred in the data store while iterating the results of a query.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name '__MigrationHistory'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Query.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__8`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__1`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryExecutor.EnumerableExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why this was closed, particularly for that reason. The edit since I first saw your question has included the details I felt required.  Also upvoted and voted to re-open.

Comment: The reason I voted to close was you didn't include a full stack trace, which is necessary to find out where the code is that was applying the migrations. Luckily Brice was on the team that wrote the thing so he had prior knowledge of where this was occurring. But in the future, if you get an exception, you should include the exception message and stack trace, and the line of code that caused the exception, and you should include it at the beginning without needing someone to ask you for it.

Comment: @AidanRyan What you call "spelunking around" the rest of us tend to call problem solving. Including a full stacktrace would have almost immediately led us to the `Database.AsMigrationsEnabled().ApplyMigrations();` line. You are very lucky that a Microsoft employee happened to see your issue, but you can't count on that. Please include a full stacktrace, error message, and relevant code next time

Comment: @AidanRyan No. It doesn't look like a full stack trace. And now that I see in your comment on Brice's answer that you don't have that line (`Database.AsMigrationsEnabled().ApplyMigrations();`), so now it becomes even more critical that you include the full stack trace.

Comment: @AidanRyan I voted to close because there was not and is not enough information to properly diagnose the problem. Closing it is not an insult, it's a signal to you that more information is needed in the question. Myself and four others felt there wasn't enough information to close it. It was not a knee-jerk reaction, and we're trying to help you, not harm you or prevent you from solving your problem. Since you say that you have provided a complete stack trace, you should look for an inner exception and check your startup code for anything migration related. Doing a Control-F may help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was `IApplicationBuilder.UseDatabaseErrorPage`. An upstream SQL error at startup was causing the `Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity` Database Error Page to render. The Database Error Page always queries the database's migrations to check if any migrations are pending, triggering the migrations system to attempt the query that produces the exception in my question.

Comment: Ah, good find. I believe I may have inadvertently fixed that issue in the nightly builds recently. I'll be sure to double check.

Answer (score 2):

If you created your project using the ASP.NET 5 Starter Web template, ASP.NET Identity has included a temporary workaround to create their database automatically using Migrations in the `ApplicationDbContext` constructor:

```
private static bool _created = false;

public ApplicationDbContext()
{            
    // Create the database and schema if it doesn't exist
    // This is a temporary workaround to create database until Entity Framework database migrations 
    // are supported in ASP.NET 5
    if (!_created)
    {
        Database.AsMigrationsEnabled().ApplyMigrations();
        _created = true;
    }
}
```

To disable Migrations, remove their workaround. :)

Otherwise, in EF7, we'll never run Migrations or any other database creation logic unless your application (or the starter template) calls methods to do so.

Comment: Hi Brice, thanks for helping out. I actually created this project from scratch and there is no call to ApplyMigrations. I am using EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta2.