# Apply EF7 Migrations on Azure

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, dnx, entity-framework-migrations

How do I apply EF7 migrations on an Azure database?

According to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx), you simply tick a box in the Publish Profile settings. Well, I don't have that checkbox - I'm not sure if the profile configuration has changed since then but I don't even have a `databases` section.

According to [this link](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/17/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-4-using-entity-framework-7), EF7 doesn't support database initializers and you have to use nuget package manager or k (dnx) migrations. I'm not sure about the nuget option, so going with the dnx option: how do I connect to my Azure (hosted) project/website using a dnx console window or the Package Manager Console in VS?

Are there any other options (hopefully easier!) for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the 'new' way:

```
_context.Database.EnsureCreated();
_context.Database.Migrate();
```

Simple.

My Azure database somehow had some migrations applied, but nothing in the __EFMigrationsHistory table, so I dropped all other tables and then ran all the migrations to get it back to where I wanted it.

Comment: Where are you running this? I have something similar in my dbcontext initializer, but that means the migrate starts throwing errors as it gets run even if there are no new migrations to add. So I'm in the sad process of adding in `Database.Migrate()` when I want to migrate, running a query once so the call happens, then taking the line out and rebuilding...

Comment: Do not use `EnsureCreated()`. Only use `Migrate()`, it will create the database if it does not exist. [See the docs on `Migrate()`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/3608b72f59ff110d75672569ea84e82288de6ab8/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L23-L35)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to apply the migrations by changing my connection string on my local project, opening the firewall on Azure to my IP address, and running a `dnx . ef migration apply` command.

However, that doesn't seem like a good solution to me: now I have to store my live connection string in my dev project and keep switching between the two. There must be a better way...?

Comment: I had the same problem and I've solved it the same way -by changing the connection string to Azure DB every time I want to apply the migration. 
Another way would be to let the application apply migrations automatically on startup. Code snippet here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28504178/19712